# making JAR files from java source folders

Tags: java, android, jar

I would like to use spongycastle api for android.

https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/archive/spongy-master.zip

However, the linked file only contains .java files, I cannot make it for eclipse external library.

Could you give me ways to build jar files from src folder. (with specific command plz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZIP file contains a `POM.xml` file, and that means you should be able to build it using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).  But there is also a script called `use-maven-layout.sh` which appears to be used for moving the files around into the Maven preferred directory layout.  You'll need to work out what is going on there for yourself.

Other alternatives are:

- manually download the pre-built JAR files from Maven Central, or
- (if you are already using Maven in your project), add the relevant dependencies to your project's POM.xml so that they downloaded automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to import the java files as a package. No need to build a jar or anything. Just click and drag all the java files (and folders in the source) into your package explorer.